# AUTO-GENERATED FILE with : 0x7f040001

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently i started android development,when i looked the R.java file it showed system generated codes with some numbers.

What do these numbers signify in `R.java`(Eclipse) **0x7f040001** ?

Below is an example :

```
 public static final int hello_world=0x7f040001;
```

Thanks

Comment: see also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is hexadecimal value Which android run time use to refer the resource.